# Dynamically load class for global access (like codeigniter does)

Tags: php, codeigniter, singleton

Here is the basics of my framework:

```
class CPU {

    public function load_class($class) {
        include_once($class . ".php");
        $this->$class = new $class;
    }

    public function load_controller($class) {
        include_once($class . ".php");
        $class = new $class;
        $class->index();
    }

    public function run() {

        // Load DB class
        $this->load_class("DB");

        // Load controller
        $this->load_controller("About");
    }
}

class About extends CPU {
    public function index() {
        $this->DB->connect();
    }
}
```

When `run()` is called to load the `About` class, accessing `$DB` gives the error below:

**Fatal error**: Call to a member function connect() on a non-object

I assume I need to use a singleton to create the class dynamically. CodeIgniter works in the same way but I can't work out what I have to do to amend my framework to make this work?

Comment: I don't see any call to `run()` in your code. Edit: disregard that, I misread. Set `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. I assume the model and controller are not in the same folder with CPU, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using [__autoload()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) or [spl_autoload_register()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) to load your classes instead hard coding the include().

About your problem, the "About" class does not ever instantiate a member of DB.  Its parent, CPU, has no DB member either.  In other words, you probably want DB to be a member of CPU or About.  It is hard to say without knowing what you are trying to do.

Even if you did make DB a member of either, you would still have to add it to the instance of the About class that is instantiated in load_controller().

In other words it seems like you are really just doing this wrong.  That DB has no connection to About at all.  It is hard to give you more help without knowing exactly what you are trying to do.

About using a Singleton, that has nothing to do with anything.  A Singleton is just a class that you only ever need one of.  They are frequently overused and misused.  Use with caution!